# using g++, how to deprecate virtual class member functions

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, g++

I seem to be having trouble getting deprecated warnings to print out, for functions declared as virtual.
I'm using "g++ (GCC) 4.1.1 20061011 (Red Hat 4.1.1-30)."
My research shows that there might be problems in gcc 4.x regarding deprecating
pure virtual functions(i.e. class bueller{ virtual int cameron()=0;};),
but not... I'd guess you'd call them regular... virtual functions.
Just so we're on the same page...

foo.h

```
class Foo
{
  void Foo_A() __attribute__((deprecated)); //non-virtual
  virtual void Foo_B() __attribute__((deprecated)); //virtual
  virtual void Foo_C() __attribute__((deprecated)) = 0; //pure virtual
};
```

Say I compiled this, an foo.cpp file and some main.cpp file using g++.

1)Anything that uses Foo_A() will indeed show a warning.

2)Anything that uses Foo_B() does NOT show a warning.

3)Anything that inherits Foo, implements Foo_C and then uses it does not show warning.

Number 1: it works, no problem.

Number 3: seems like a known bug/feature.. whatever..

There seems to be no explination for #2 however.
Perhaps it's tied up in #3, although nothing I've found makes mention of it.

Anyone know if I'm missing anything here regarding regular virtual class member functions that I want to deprecate?

BTW: -Wno-deprecate is NOT turned on in my makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this program:

```
struct Foo
{
  virtual void Foo_B() __attribute__((deprecated)); //virtual
};

struct DerivedFoo : public Foo
{
};


int main()
{
  DerivedFoo d;
  d.Foo_B();
  Foo &f = d;
  f.Foo_B();
}
void Foo::Foo_B() {}
```

On CentOS 5.2 (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)), I get the same output that you describe:

```
g++     deprecate.cc   -o deprecate
deprecate.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
deprecate.cc:14: warning: ‘Foo_B’ is deprecated (declared at deprecate.cc:3)
```

But, on Ubuntu 10.04.1 (gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)), I get the output that you expect:

```
g++     deprecate.cc   -o deprecate
deprecate.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
deprecate.cc:14: warning: ‘virtual void Foo::Foo_B()’ is deprecated (declared at deprecate.cc:3)
deprecate.cc:16: warning: ‘virtual void Foo::Foo_B()’ is deprecated (declared at deprecate.cc:3)
```

So, I'm guessing it was a compiler bug that got fixed.

Comment: Rob, what happens when you use dynamic memory and the -> operator instead of using the . operator? Does it behave the same? I'm running gentoo and not Ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: When I change "d" and "f" to pointers, and the calls to `->Foo_B()`, I still get two warnings.

Comment: Thanks for checking Rob. Also, thanks to Staffan for his help as well. That solves the mystery of the missing deprecation warning. It was old man Johnson. Good job team!

Answer (score 0):

Do you call Foo_B()/Foo_C() through a Foo pointer/reference, or a derived class? If you use a derived class it seems that you have to mark the methods deprecated in it as well, or you get the behaviour you describe.

Comment: You are correct in that I do derive a class from "Foo", but I do not actually override those functions in question.  I would imagine that unless I override a base class's function, I would not need to declare that derived class's overriden function as deprecated.... or at all, since i'm not overriding it.  Perhaps it's the virtual table getting in the way? In that through the course of execution, DerivedFoo::Foo_B() is getting called (even though it's not explicitly overriden in class DerivedFoo) instead of the base class's Foo::Foo_B()? Both equate to the same method in the end I think.

Comment: Well that seems to be the case, however. The behaviour you describe is the same for GCC 4.5.1 as well. The GCC manual doesn't offer much of an explanation, I suggest you ask at one of their mailing lists if you feel the current behaviour could be improved.

Comment: I agree with you on the manual part. I looked there first. Just so that I have this straight... you're telling me that for the deprecated  warning message to show up, I'd have to do something like this...  void DerivedFoo::Foo_B(){ Foo::Foo_B();}? Well, that kinda sucks. Albeit of me to dare assume what the GCC guys are thinking, but I would imagine that if you had a base function marked deprecated, you'd want a warning to spit out mentioning that you've inherited and overriden a deprecated function, because all those access to that function from base class pointers go BOOM.

Comment: That should do the trick, yes. Or you can mark them deprecated in the in the derived class as well, but then you'll have to re-implement them as well I guess, so that's pretty much the same.

Comment: Seems like this might be a bug in GCC. http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15269 suggests that this was fixed for virtual methods in GCC 4.3, but I still see the same behaviour as you with GCC 4.5.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised they mark it fixed in 4.3 and it still shows up in 4.5. Is there another c++ compiler, like Microsoft for example, that does not exhibit this behavior? I think I read somewhere that there is no standardized way in C++ to do deprecation.

Comment: There's no standardized way to mark a function/type as deprecated, no. __attribute__((deprecated)) is GCC-specific. For Visual C++ you can use "#pragma deprecated" to mark functions as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Google shows an old [discussion](http://lists.debian.org/debian-gcc/2004/05/msg00037.html) on this topic at a Debian list.  But nothing more recent comes up on this topic.  Try asking on the distribution's (RedHat's, in this case) lists.